# Verifying this limit of a sum

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, bernoulli-numbers

A lenghty  limit, $$\lim_{ n \to \infty}-\sqrt{8}\cdot \frac{n!}{B_n}\sum_{j=0}^{n}\frac{(1-2^{1-j})(1-2^{1+j-n})B_{n-j}B_j}{4^j(n-j)!j!}=\pi$$

The limit seems to appraoches to $\pi$ but I am not able to shows it.

where $B_n$ is the [Bernoulli number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_number)

Can anyone help to verify this limit is correct?

Comment: Have you tried rearranging the terms such that you have $\binom{n}{j} = \frac{n!}{j! (n-j)!}$, which is easily summable.

Comment: Which sign convention are you using? Also, since some $B_n$ are $0$, many terms in the limit are undefined. Did you use the notation where $B_n$ is written instead of $B_ {2n}$?

Comment: $$\sum_{j=0}^{n}\frac{(1-2^{1-j})(1-2^{1+j-n})B_{n-j}B_j}{4^j(n-j)!j!} = \sum_{j=0}^{n}\frac{(1-2^{1-j})B_{j}}{j!}\frac{(1-2^{1-(n-j)})B_{n-j}}{(n-j)!} = \sum_{j=0}^{n}a_jb_{n-j}$$
is the coefficient of $z^n$ in Cauchy product of
$$\dfrac{z}{e^z-1}e^{-z/2}=\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\frac{(1-2^{1-m})B_{m}}{m!}$$
with itself, but $4^j$ in denominator must to justify.